# Два наречия подряд

Tags: наречия

Два наречия подряд иногда как-то настораживают:

> Вообще сейчас все поменялось.
>   Он пока очень слабый.

Ведь уху будет приятнее со словом-связкой:

> Он пока что очень слабый.
>   Вообще же сейчас все поменялось.

Есть ли какие-то рекомендации в русском языке по этому поводу или все это бестолковые изыски?

PS. Хотя есть логичные примеры и с тремя наречиями подряд:

> Завтра слишком долго не спим!

Comment: *> или все это бестолковые изыски?* Бестолковые изыски.

Comment: Очень режет ухо два наречия подряд в объявлении в поездах метро: "Будьте взаимно вежливы". По-моему правильно будет "будьте взаимовежливы" или "будьте взаимно вежливыми".

Comment: Простите, а где тут ДВА наречия? Вежливы — это краткая форма от "вежливые". https://kartaslov.ru/просклонять-прилагательное/вежливый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вообще сейчас все поменялось. Он пока очень слабый.**

Два (и даже три) наречия подряд встречаются в русском языке, но при этом важно правильно построить структуру предложения.

Необособленные наречия являются неоднородными обстоятельствами: **Он пока очень слабый.** *Пока* – обстоятельство времени, *очень* – обстоятельство степени.

Но второе наречие может быть **уточняющим** обособленным обстоятельством, например: *На покривившемся стогу **уныло, по-сиротски,** примостилась ворона* (Ф.);

Эту тему можно посмотреть у Розенталя, там много примеров: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Итак, мы можем построить предложение с двумя наречиями-обстоятельствами, обособленными или необособленными. Но это зависит не только от значения наречий, но и от структуры предложения.

Предложение должно удобно читаться. **Обычно рядом могут стоять два наречия, которые при чтении можно объединить в одну фразу**:

Вообще сейчас // всё поменялось. И даже так: З*десь вообще сейчас // всё поменялось.*

Исправленный пример: Мы **вчера очень долго** // не ложились спать.

Три наречия входят в первую часть предложения, то есть вписываются в одну интонационную фразу, но при этом порядок слов нужно подбирать.